# MS SQL: INSERT values from another table and values from constant data

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to insert values into a table named EMPLOYEE_PROGRAM_LEVEL. Here are the column names I need to specify:

```
EMPLOYEE_ID, PROGRAM_ID, LEVEL, MANAGE_ACCESS
```

Before doing the insertion, I know only the employee name and the program name. LEVEL and MANAGE_ACCESS are known constants that I need to hardcode in the query.

The problem is: I need to get the id corresponding to the employee name and the id corresponding to the program name but I also need to insert the constant values in the same query!

I've tried:

```
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE_PROGRAM_LEVEL(EMPLOYEE_ID, PROGRAM_ID, LEVEL, MANAGE_ACCESS)

SELECT ID, ID_PROGRAM FROM EMPLOYEE T1
INNER JOIN PROGRAM T2 ON T2.NOM='programName'
WHERE T1.USERNAME='userName'

VALUES(ID, ID_PROGRAM, '9000', 'O');
```

'9000' and 'O' are the fixed values(LEVEL and MANAGE_ACCESS columns)
Apparently, I can't use VALUES in a INSERT SELECT QUERY which is blocking me. Here's the error I get:

```
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'VALUES'.
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE_PROGRAM_LEVEL(EMPLOYEE_ID, PROGRAM_ID, LEVEL, MANAGE_ACCESS)
SELECT ID, ID_PROGRAM,'9000', 'O' 
FROM EMPLOYEE T1
INNER JOIN PROGRAM T2 ON T2.NOM='programName'
WHERE T1.USERNAME='userName'
```

Answer (score 2):

You're almost there, just need to add the constants to the SELECT:

```
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE_PROGRAM_LEVEL(EMPLOYEE_ID, PROGRAM_ID, LEVEL, MANAGE_ACCESS)
SELECT ID, ID_PROGRAM, '9000', 'O'
FROM EMPLOYEE T1
INNER JOIN PROGRAM T2 ON T2.NOM='programName'
WHERE T1.USERNAME='userName'
```

Answer (score -1):

Avoid inner join of full tables. Join only filtered datasets since it will make better performance

So, result should look like the following:

```
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE_PROGRAM_LEVEL(EMPLOYEE_ID, PROGRAM_ID, LEVEL, MANAGE_ACCESS)
SELECT ID, ID_PROGRAM,'9000', 'O' 
FROM (SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE WHERE USERNAME='userName') as T1
INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM PROGRAM WHERE NOM='programName') as T2 ON 1 = 1
```

ADDED:

Also, you can avoid data duplication for the case if you have any program or employee with the same name. It can be performed by TOP. See sample:

```
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE_PROGRAM_LEVEL(EMPLOYEE_ID, PROGRAM_ID, LEVEL, MANAGE_ACCESS)
SELECT ID, ID_PROGRAM,'9000', 'O' 
FROM (SELECT TOP 1 * FROM EMPLOYEE WHERE USERNAME='userName') as T1
INNER JOIN (SELECT TOP 1 * FROM PROGRAM WHERE NOM='programName') as T2 ON 1 = 1
```

One more trick: you can specify what record should be accounted by the script if duplicates are found. Let say you have skillLevel for each employee which defines a priority of the requested employee. Additionaly, let say you have priority field for program which does the same thing for programs. In this case you can use order for that. See example:

```
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE_PROGRAM_LEVEL(EMPLOYEE_ID, PROGRAM_ID, LEVEL, MANAGE_ACCESS)
SELECT ID, ID_PROGRAM,'9000', 'O' 
FROM (SELECT TOP 1 * FROM EMPLOYEE WHERE USERNAME='userName' ORDER BY skillLevel DESC) as T1
INNER JOIN (SELECT TOP 1 * FROM PROGRAM WHERE NOM='programName' ORDER BY priority DESC) as T2 ON 1 = 1
```

Use ASC if minimal value is defining maximum priority

Comment: "Avoid inner join of full tables. Join only filtered datasets since it will make better performance" - The internal query optimizer does all this for you. The only result this will give is making your code less readable.

Comment: Compare the code on result set in 100 million records. You will see that internal optimizer is not so good as it appears on advertisement :)